# Waiting 20 seconds in iMacros

Tags: imacros

U have **imacros** script and  I want to add **wait seconds 60** When **`i`** reach to **20**.

This is my code now:

```
var macro;

macro = "CODE:";

macro += "URL GOTO=http://example.com/msg?uid={{i}}\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:msg ATTR=ID:subject CONTENT=hello\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:msg ATTR=ID:message CONTENT=hi\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:IMAGE FORM=NAME:msg ATTR=ID:btn_save";

for (var i=1;i<300;i++){
    iimSet("i",i)
    iimPlay(macro)
}

iimDisplay("Script completed.");
```

And I also tried this one:

```
var macro;

macro = "CODE:";

macro += "URL GOTO=http://example.com/msg?uid={{i}}\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:msg ATTR=ID:subject CONTENT=hello\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:msg ATTR=ID:message CONTENT=hi\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:IMAGE FORM=NAME:msg ATTR=ID:btn_save";
iimDisplay("Send Macro via iimPlay");
retcode = iimPlay(macro);

var i=2

while(true){

    if(i%20==0){    
        iimPlay("CODE: WAIT SECONDS=60")
    }

    iimSet("i",i);
    iimPlay(macro);
}

for (var i=1;i<999;i++){
    iimSet("i",i)
    iimPlay(macro)
}

iimDisplay("Script completed.");
```

But both code are not working for me. Can anybody help me? Thank you !

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn from it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code change the loop in the following way:

```
for (i = 1; i < 300; i++){
    if (i == 20)
        iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=60");
    iimSet("i", i);
    iimPlay(macro);
}
```