# iMacros -- If site loads, wait; otherwise ignore

Tags: if-statement, imacros

i am using Imacros Add-on with Firefox
this is My Code

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST
TAB T=1

'open the proxy file
SET !DATASOURCE C:\proxy.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}
URL GOTO=http://mywebsite.com
WAIT SECONDS=25
```

Now i want that if URL loads and not Gives Error than it Wait 25 Seconds, and if URL does not Load Then it Ends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting 20 seconds in iMacros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902210/waiting-20-seconds-in-imacros)

Comment: @Smandoli can u please convert my script as i dont have any idea of javascript.

Comment: That is different, I see ... although they are both iMacros.  I took away my "Duplicate" tag.  But I can't help with your script.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very simple to apply the JavaScript Scripting Interface. Let’s suppose that if your URL gives an error, the title of the web-page matches some text. (I assumed ‘Error’ or ‘Problem’. Certainly, you can use another text or tag.) Here is a macro which does what you need:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 15
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST

'open the proxy file
SET !DATASOURCE C:\proxy.csv
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

TAB T=1
PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL1}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=http://mywebsite.com
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TITLE ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET E EVAL("('{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/Error|Problem/i)) ? MacroError('THE PAGE NOT LOADED ! ') : '';")
WAIT SECONDS=25
```